# Processing XML in ASP Pages - Part 2

Tags: xml, xpath, asp-classic

Folks....This is a follow up to a similar question I asked recently.  How can I retrieve a specific value from an XML structure without travelling down the structure and iterating through all of the childnodes?  It was suggested that I should use XPath.

Assume the following simplified XML structure:

```
<MyWeather>
    <sensor location="Front Entry">
    <reading label="Temperature">
        <title>Front Entry</title>
        <label>Temperature</label>
        <value>54</value>
        <units>F</units>
        <lastUpdate>05/27/2013 12:23 AM</lastUpdate>
    </reading>
    <reading label="Humidity">
        <title>Front Entry</title>
        <label>Humidity</label>
        <value>66</value>
        <units>%</units>
        <lastUpdate>05/27/2013 12:23 AM</lastUpdate>
    </reading>
</sensor>
<sensor location="Patio">
    <reading label="Temperature">
        <title>Patio</title>
        <label>Temperature</label>
        <value>46</value>
        <units>F</units>
        <lastUpdate>05/27/2013 12:23 AM</lastUpdate>
    </reading>
    <reading label="Humidity">
        <title>Patio</title>
        <label>Humidity</label>
        <value>93</value>
        <units>%</units>
        <lastUpdate>05/27/2013 12:23 AM</lastUpdate>
    </reading>

    </sensor>
</MyWeather>
```

Here is part of my ASP page:

```
<%
xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmldoc.setProperty ("ServerHTTPRequest", true)
xmlDoc.setProperty ("ProhibitDTD", False)
xmlDoc.validateOnParse = true

'    Filename is a sting variable containing the URL

xmlDoc.async = "False"
xmlDoc.load(FileName)

'    Error and return code processing done here but removed 

For Each el In xmldoc.childNodes
    if el.childnodes.length <> 0 then
    response.write ("<table align='center' class='auto-style1'>")
    for each el2 in el.childnodes
        Response.write("<tr><td>" & el2.getattribute("location") & "</td><td></td></tr>")
        for each el3 in el2.childnodes
            for each el4 in el3.childnodes
            if el4.nodename = "value" then 
            Response.write("<tr><td></td><td>" & el3.getattribute("label") & " " & el4.text & " " & el4.nextSibling.text & "</td></tr>")
            exit for
              end if
          next
          next
      next
    response.write ("</table>")
    end if
  Next
xmlDoc = Nothing

%>
```

My question relates to the code in the "*For each el4 in ...*"  section.  You see that I iterate through the childnodes until I find "value". Then I output that tag value and, as I know the next tag (for now until they change it), is the "units" tag I use nextsibling to get that value.  **This code works!**

What I would like to know is: 
Is there a more direct way to these two tag values for any combination of *Sensor location* and *Reading label* without my iteration process.

I have several other cases where I may need to iterate through more than 50 elements to find the tag I'm looking for.

I added this xPath code based on a recommendation from my previous question. This, if it worked would replace the "*for each el4 in el3.childnodes loop*" above

```
xmlDoc.setProperty ("SelectionLanguage", "XPath")

                oNode = xmldoc.selectSingleNode("//reading[@label='Temperaure']/units")
                o2Node = xmldoc.selectSingleNode("//reading[@label='Temperaure']/value")
                if oNode is nothing or o2node is nothing then
                    Response.write("<tr><td></td><td> Nothing found for value or units </td><td>" & el3.getattribute("label") & "</tr>") 
                  else
                    Response.write("<tr><td></td><td>" & el3.getattribute("label") & " " & o2Node.text & " " & oNode.text & "</td></tr>")
                  end if
```

However, it did not work for me.  I tried several variations: without the @ sign and with a full path in the oNode statements, ie /MyWeather/sensor/reading/...

My check for empty oNode and/or O2Node always is true.

Any ideas?.....RDK

Comment: Are you really querying on "Temperaure"? Then you'd better fix that typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already traversed the tree a bit with all your nested `For Each` loops then to replace a further nested `For Each` you need to make sure you call the `selectSingleNode` on the variable in the outer `For Each` and you use a relative path e.g.

```
  Response.Write el3.selectSingleNode("value").text
```

I would strongly suggest to not use childNodes at all but simply to make sure you use `selectNodes` with the path of elements you are interested in, that way it is much clearer which element nodes you are processing; for instance if you really check that the XML input has been parsed successfully with error checking then

```
For Each el In xmldoc.childNodes
    if el.childnodes.length <> 0 then
    response.write ("<table align='center' class='auto-style1'>")
```

is superfluous as a well-formed XML document always has a root element child node so once you have check e.g

```
  If xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode = 0 Then
    Response.Write ("<table align='center' class='auto-style1'>")
```

should suffice.

If you then want to access the root element (in your case the `MyWheater` element) it suffices to use `xmlDoc.documentElement`.

Further on you can then use

```
  For Each sensor In xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("sensor")
    Dim tr
    Set tr = sensor.selectSingleNode("reading[@label = 'Temperature']")
    Response.Write tr.selectSingleNode("value").text & " " & tr.selectSingleNode("unit").text
  Next
```

The only gotcha with XML is namespaces, if your real XML has attributes like `xmlns="http://example.com"` or if any DTD you have sets such attributes as defaults then with MSXML you need to use e.g.

```
  xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:df='http://example.com'"
```

and further on you need to use that prefix (e.g. `df`) to qualify element names in your XPath expressions passed to `selectNodes` and `selectSingleNode` i.e.

```
  For Each sensor In xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("df:sensor")
    Dim tr
    Set tr = sensor.selectSingleNode("df:reading[@label = 'Temperature']")
    Response.Write tr.selectSingleNode("df:value").text & " " & tr.selectSingleNode("df:unit").text
  Next
```

Comment: WOW!!!! Thanks for the detailed and well documented reply.  I'm impressed.  Unfortunately I about to leave for a few days so I won't get to study and apply your suggestions right away.  I WILL get back when I have tried them. Thanks again.

Comment: Martin.....Again thanks for your reply.  I have studied your comments and applied them successfully to my project.  Again kudos.

I also need to thank Jens Erat for catching my typo which most certainly caused some of my earlier problems.